# Можно ли проверить корректность геометрии нарисованного пользователем многоугольника?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Возникла задача отбраковывать нарисованные пользователем многоугольники с некорректной геометрией (например, пользователь случайно ставит очередную вершину где-то внутри многоугольника, получая пересечение сторон). Хотелось бы такие случаи отлавливать и просить пользователя сделать исправление. Кроме того, такая проверка должна быть сделана и для уже готовых многоугольников, а не только для тех, которые рисуются пользователем вновь. Подходящего функционала в Yandex Maps JSAPI не нашел. P.S. Интересует готовый функционал, а не написание своего алгоритма для валидации геометрии, так как мне уж тогда проще проверить геометрию силами функции st_isvalid в MySQL (многоугольники сохраняются в БД как объекты типа Polygon).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить:

- не пересекаются ли стороны
- нет ли общих точек, кроме начальной и последней

Перебирая стороны, можно одновременно проверить и точки, то есть достаточно одного цикла.

Comment: Понятно. Я ожидал, что таки есть какое-то готовое решение у Яндекса, но не писать самому подобный алгоритм. Зачем это нужно? Нарисованные пользователем многоугольники (зоны) сохраняются в БД MySQL как объекты типа Polygon, в последствии могут быть выполнены различные геозапросы на уровне БД (ну, например, определение того, входит ли какая-то точка в указанную зону). Но такие запросы могут работать только с корректной геометрией. Мне уж тогда легче делать проверку корректности геометрии силами MySQL при добавлении/обновлении записи, чем тратить время на написание своего алгоритма на JS.